# How to show only slice text in MPAndroidChart PieChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use the library [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to draw a pie chart.

I want to show only the slice text(X) and not the value of the slice(Y).
The only way that I have found is to Override the Valuesformatter and send always an empty string.

```
data.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter()
        {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value)
            {
                //return formatter_currency.format(value) + " " + currency;         
                return ""; // Display only categories name.
            }
        });
```

But in this way all the names doesn't fit the slice correctly(there is the empty string under it).

There is a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, **there is a way**.

Call:

`pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false)`

to disable drawing the x-labels for the chart-slices.

If you want to disable the y-values, call:

`dataSet.setDrawValues(false)`

**EDIT:**  `setDrawSliceText()` is now deprecated use `setDrawEntryLabels()` instead.

Comment: Hi Philipp! I want to draw only the X-labels. For example if a slice have X = "Name" and Y = 10 in the slice I would see only "Name"

Comment: I just tested it and there might be a bug in the API. I fixed it in the latest commit.

Comment: dataSet.setDrawValues(false); delete X and also Y values. However thanks for the good work, I just switched from acharengine to your library :D I wait for your update

Comment: @PhilippJahoda It seems the Jar library hasn't been update yet. I just download the newest jar, the problem still exists.

Comment: @PhilipJahoda Hey Philip is there anyway to draw the labels outside of the pie chart instead of in the actual pie slices ??

Comment: @PhilippJahoda..Can you please answer this question ? [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283022/how-to-get-selected-pie-slice-text-and-value-on-onvalueselected-in-mpandroid-cha ]