# How to get selected label for Entry inside onValueSelected() in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have written the following `OnChartValueSelectedListener` for my pie chart. I am able to get the value with the code below. However, I would like to get the text label as well. In the code below, `e.getY()` will get the y-value. How do I get the text label for the `Entry`?

```
holder.chartyear.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
            Log.e("VAL SELECTED", "Value: " + e.getY() + ", index: " + h.getX()
                            + ", DataSet index: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cast the `Entry` as a `PieEntry` and then use the method `getLabel()`.

```
@Override 
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
    PieEntry pe = (PieEntry) e;
    Log.e("LABEL",pe.getLabel());
}
```